# Inequality operator cannot resolve boolean and int datatype

Tags: python, sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table Neg_days containing 4 columns,
`Account number(long)`, `days_neg(int)`, `days_pos(int)`, `days_neg_pos(int)`.
The latter 3 columns have mostly null values and one row contatining zeroes.

When I try to perform the comparison operator:

```
spark.sql ="""
select nd.account_number
 , case when days_neg > days_pos > days_neg_pos then 1 else 0 end as new_column
from Neg_days as nd
"""
spark.sql.createOrreplaceTempView("Accounts_down")
```

The error thrown is:

```
couldnt resolve the (days_neg > days_pos > days_neg_pos) due to datatype mismatch.
Couldnt resolve bool and int
```

I have already changed the datatype to int so I cant understand where the bool datatype is coming from

Comment: SQL Server does not support 3+ expressions in a Boolean clause, only 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boolean datatype comes from the comparison operation. SQL is not Python and you cannot have shortcuts like `A > B > C`. This will be evaluated as `(A > B) > C`. If A, B, and C are integers, you end up with `bool > int` and hence the error. Instead, you need to write `A > B AND B > C`.